# Bsearch with strings in C

Tags: c, binary-search, bsearch

So I'm trying to use the bsearch function in C to do a binary search in an array of strings. For some reason, it always returns NULL. For the compare function of bsearch I didn't use strcmp, I made my own which, surprisingly, works for my manual implementation of the binary search function. I'll explain in a bit, anyway, here's my main code:

```
int main(){

  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if(n<=0) qerror();

  char ** words = (char **)calloc(n, sizeof(char *));
  if(words == NULL) qerror();
  int i = 0;
  for(;i<n;i++){

    words[i] = (char *)calloc(MAX, sizeof(char));
    if(words[i] == NULL) qerror();
    scanf("%s", words[i]);

  }

  char seek_word[MAX];
  scanf("%s", seek_word);
  char ** c = (char **)bsearch(seek_word, words, n, sizeof(char *), &b_compare_words);

  if(c == NULL) printf("-1\n");
  else printf("%d\n", c - words);


  //printf("%d\n", bin_search_string(words, n, seek_word)); //manuelna binarna pretraga
  free(words);

  return 0;
}
```

The first part of this code is just creating an array of strings (named words) that contains N strings of the length MAX (which is a macro defined at the beginning). I've tested this part and it works, so that's not the problem.

Afterwards, the seek_word is inputted, which is just the word that we're trying to find in 'words'. The I call the bsearch and as a compare function I used the function that I've created myself. Here's what it looks like:

```
int compare_words(char * a, char * b){
  int i = 0;
  while(a[i] && b[i]){

    char ac = tolower(a[i]), bc = tolower(b[i]);
    if(ac < bc) return -1;
    else if (ac > bc) return 1;
    i++;

  }
  return 0;
}

int b_compare_words(const void * a, const void * b){
  return compare_words((char *)a, (char *)b);
}
```

The actual comparison work is done in the compare_words function which I've called from the b_compare_words function where I've just casted the void pointers into char pointers.
And whatever I test this on, I get -1 (meaning the pointer returned by bsearch is NULL).
Now here's the interesting part. Apart from this I've made my own binary search function that does the same thing and it works (you can see the part that I commented out below). The function is called bin_search_string and it looks like this:

```
int bin_search_string(char ** a, int n, char * x){

    int l_index = 0;
    int r_index = n-1;
    int check_index;
    while(l_index <= r_index){
      check_index = l_index + (r_index - l_index)/2;
      int test = compare_words(x, a[check_index]);
      if(test == 0) return check_index;
      else if(test < 0) l_index = check_index + 1;
      else r_index = check_index - 1;

    }
    return -1;

}
```

As you can see, this function uses the same compare_words function that I've also passed to bsearch. But when I test my program using my own function, it really works (returns the index where the string was found).
So, any ideas why the bsearch won't work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't forget to sort your words, did you?

Comment: I didn't look at the rest, but your `compare_words` is broken (given `"foo"` and `"foobar"` it will return 0).

Comment: Binary search algorithm ASSUMES a sorted array.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight and Peter  The arrays I'm testing on are indeed sorted.
MatteoItalia  Yeah, I haven't noticed that, nice catch. I'll try to fix it and post an update

Comment: It is not enough for the array to be sorted, it must be sorted using the same comparison function. In your case that would mean case-insensitive sorting of the array.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The arrays are indeed sorted using the same comparison function.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I've fixed my function, now it works in those cases (tested with foo and foobar and some other examples I could think of). However, the arrays I'm testing with contain no such cases. So it still doesn't work, I guess it wasn't related to that specific problem.